# Create an empty table from an existing table keeping the default value constraint

Tags: sql-server, constraint, select-into

I tried:

```
Select * Into <DestinationTableName> From <SourceTableName> Where 1 = 2
```

but the default value constraint is not created.

I have a `smalldatetime` column whose default value is `getdate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with quick and easy short-cuts.

it just takes a bit of work.  ;-)

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query

Create a user defined function using the code from the link, then you can exec the output...

```
snip...
select @tsql = dbo.udf_GenerateTableCreateScript(N'dbo.mytable')
exec @tsql
```